# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (maven + jboss)

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jboss, jboss7.x

maven pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Test</groupId>
<artifactId>Test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Test</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In code Im trying to execute `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`.

I get this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

But I have checked I have mysql.jar in `jboss-as-7.0.2.Final\standalone\deployments\Test.war\WEB-INF\lib` and it has com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class.

Comment: The `servlet-api` dependency should be marked as `provided`, btw.

Comment: What is the exact name of `mysql.jar` file that you have in `..WEB-INF\lib` ?

Comment: @Dᴀᴠᴇ Nᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ Thx, I did not know, I will try.@ring bearer mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar

Comment: @itun - how are you executing your code? via the build or IDE or command line ?

Comment: via IDE which has specific JBoss Maven plugin to deploy projects

Comment: Do you have the mysql jar added to your project's build path ( for example in eclipse) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule you should not be including your JDBC drivers in your war file.

I suggest you mark the driver as provided and add it to the lib directory of the server.

PS. I'm not sure why you would be using

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

in your code. Why not let the contain manage your connections and transactions?

Comment: for JBoss AS7, there is no lib directory on the server, so this answer won't fix it either. Correct way is to use data sources provided by the container.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred because your mysql jar is not on your run-time class-path. If you are using maven,

1. Open your EAR/web project properties
2. Click on "Deployment Assembly"
3. Click on "Add..."
4. Select on "Java Build Path Entries"
5. Click on "Next"
6. Select "Maven Dependencies"
7. Click "Finish"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using JBoss AS7. Check instructions here: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7

Basically, you should

1. Install mysql connector
2. Create a data source using it
3. Refer to that data source using JNDI configuration

Class.forName() is an idiom commonly used when data sources are not provided by the container. In modern Java EE servers, they are provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different use case. I was using apache's BasicDataSource in a stand-alone application.

I got this exception because I was calling `setDriverClassName` with `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class.toString()` instead of `"com.mysql.jdbc.Drive"` as a String (so compile time check ensures that there is no typo or Driver's location didn't change in a version upgrade... etc).

But!

When you look Driver's implementation it has a static initialization block:

```
static {
  try {
    java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
  } catch (SQLException E) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Can't register driver!");
  }
}
```

When I wrote `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class.toString()` this initialization block executed too early and caused later on misleading `ClassNotFoundException` to be thrown. Once I switched to `"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"` my application started to work.

*This is a case when static becomes evil* :)