# Maven Update changes .classpath failing build while war packaging

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment, war

I've a Spring Maven webapp project which is to be deployed in Tomcat.

I want to package my project to .war for which I've my POM.xml as follows.

```
<!-- Other settings -->    

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- other settings -->
```

With this setting, when I do *Maven -> Update* from m2eclipse and *Run as -> Run on Server*, it gives `ClassNotFoundException` for `ContextLoaderListener`.

But when I add `Maven Dependencies` to my java build path from `Deployment Assembly` from project properties as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15780350/1433665 , the project runs fine. But again when I do *Maven Update*, same problem persists.

How can I configure my `pom.xml` such that I don't have to edit `Deployment Assembly` settings everytime I do `Maven -> Update` ?

Also, only file that is changed after *Maven -> Update* is `.classpath` in which

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">

    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

is updated to

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">

    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```